# How to get the number of m2m attribute with a conditional in Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

For example, there have two class in Django model:

```
class Generus(models.Model):
    user    = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    LIST_KLP = (
        ('Marbar', 'Marbar'),
        ('Marsel', 'Marsel'),
    )
    klp = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=LIST_KLP, default='Marbar')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name

class Event(models.Model):
    LIST_EVENT = (
        ('Mince', 'Mince'),
        ('Persami', 'Persami'),
    )
    name_event = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=LIST_EVENT, default='Persami')
    attendance = models.ManyToManyField(Generus, related_name='foo', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.jenis_kegiatan, self.tanggal)
```

From those class, I want to get the number of the attendance which has the klp = Marsel. Is there any possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should be able to do...

```
Event.objects.filter(foo__klp='Marsel')
```

Comment: Great, thank you! But, how to get the number of attendance in a specific event?

Comment: assume you have some event `e`. `e.attendance` will get you a list of all `Generus` instances associated with `e`.  From there it's just `len()`